# OpenCV HOGDescriptor HEAP crash

Tags: c++, opencv

I have some issue with the `cv::HOGDescriptor` in opencv 2.4.2 in Visual Studio 2012.

```
vector<cv::Rect> found, found_filtered;
cv::HOGDescriptor hog;
hog.setSVMDetector(cv::HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector()); // CRASH HERE
hog.detectMultiScale(tempFrame, found, 0, cv::Size(8, 8), cv::Size(32, 32), 1.05, 2);
```

It is absolutely a copy of the example code which runs in XCode but not in Visual Studio 2012.

The error message is

```
HEAP[Project.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 00C80000, 02D51150 )
Project.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
```

Has anyone experience with that kind of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. right click Project - Properties
2. Configurational Properties - General - set Plattform Toolset: "Visual Studio 2010 (v100)"
3. Configurational Properties - C/C++ - Code Generation - set Runtime Library: "Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)" for debug builds or "Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)" for release build